# The Pen and the Pocket

Tags: riddle

A student who has just arrived to a class and takes some writing materials out of his pocket and places them on the desk. After a few minutes, he realizes that his pen (one that needs a cap) doesn't have it's cap on. He doesn't know if it came off when he took it out of his pocket or somewhere else. He carefully examines his pocket and then decides not to look for the cap. The cap was not in his pocket. Why did he not look anywhere else?

Comment: This riddle popped into my head today when I was searching for my own pen cap. I used the same strategy this fictional character did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe:

> He noticed wet ink in his pocket.  Wet ink means that while the pen was in his pocket, it had no cap and leaked.  This was before he put the pen in his pocket, so at any point **before** he got to class.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I got it!  Sorry you had to use the same strategy...

Comment: @BrendonShaw sorry for your loss. Also, have you considered pocket protectors?

Answer (score 9):

Because

> He found a death threat on a note from the thief in his pocket saying that him and his family would be murdered in their sleep if he ever tried to learn about the were about of his pen cap.

Or

> He found a hole in his pocket which made him realize the pen cap could be anywhere.

Or

> He realized that a 10 cent cap was not worth more than 10 seconds of his life.

Or probably simply that

> His course was about to begin and had no time to do any thorough searches for a cap which was totally not necessary for the class anyway.

Comment: Nope! Good guesses though. He didn't have any holes in his pockets, he was willing to search for the cap, and no one was threatening him.

Comment: Death threat hahahahaha +1

Answer (score 4):

Maybe he realised

> That is was a pop open pen that you click(they don't have caps).

OR

> The cap of this specific pen was on another one of the writing materials.

Comment: No. It needs a cap. Good guess though! I'll edit this so that the answer can't be this.

Comment: Ahh I see :)   P.S. welcome to PSE! @BrendonShaw

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an opposite to @Greg's answer.

> He found no ink in his pocket and realized the pen had run out of ink